# How to customize Axis Security Header for the following XML using Stub

Tags: java, web-services, axis, apache-axis

I am trying to automate the xml web services using Apache Axis Java API and I have generated the stubs. But my Below XML has header part which i need to customize manually using stub.

So I have used `SOAPHeaderElement` from stub class and designed the code. But I am getting extra namespace like `xmlns:wsse=""` in each node and `soapenv:` in header node.

So, please modify my code to get the exact format(Expected) as given below

**Below is the XML Header Part:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Header mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
               <wsse:Username>InternalServiceUser</wsse:Username>
               <wsse:Password>123456</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
         </wsse:Security>
      </wsse:Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

**Below is the code:**

```
        SOAPHeaderElement wsseHeader = new SOAPHeaderElement(new  PrefixedQName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Header", "wsse")); 
        String nullString = null;
        MessageElement Security = new MessageElement(nullString, "wsse:Security");
        MessageElement usernameToken = new MessageElement(nullString, "wsse:UsernameToken");
        MessageElement username = new MessageElement(nullString, "wsse:Username");
        MessageElement password = new MessageElement(nullString, "wsse:Password");
        username.setObjectValue("InternalServiceUser");
        usernameToken.addChild(username);
        password.setObjectValue("123456");
        usernameToken.addChild(password);
        Security.addChild(usernameToken);
        wsseHeader.addChild(Security);
        wsseHeader.setActor(null);
        wsseHeader.setMustUnderstand(true);

        _call.addHeader(wsseHeader);
```

**Expected Request XML Header part:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Header mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
               <wsse:Username>InternalServiceUser</wsse:Username>
               <wsse:Password>123456</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
         </wsse:Security>
      </wsse:Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

**Actual request XML header part which is generated after execution:**

could not remove soapenv: in header tag and xmlns:wsse="" in Security, Username and password tags via code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Header soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=""><wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="">
<wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="">InternalServiceUser</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password xmlns:wsse="">123456</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</wsse:Header>
</soapenv:Header>
```